# Empty string when get xml string from a node in java

Tags: java, xml

I get an error when I transform an `xml node` to an `xml string`. I want to get the SDG node and transform it to an `xml String`, but what I got is just an empty string.

This is the sources:

```
 public class StringToDocumentToString {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = convertStringToDocument();

    String str = convertDocumentToString(doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild());
    System.out.println(str);
}

private static String convertDocumentToString(Node doc) {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        // below code to remove XML declaration
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
         transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();
        return output;
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static Document convertStringToDocument() {
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\data.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
    DocumentBuilder builder;  
    try 
    {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        Document doc = builder.parse( fXmlFile ); 
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
    return null;
}
```

}

And Xml Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:data key="SDG" xmlns:ns2="http:my.example.com" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
    <SDG SI="General" xmlns="http:my.example.com">
        <SD SI="Classification">EventOrderTest</SD>
        <SD SI="RequiredInterfaces">None</SD>
    </SDG>
</ns2:data>
```

What is wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**Solved:**

Follow the solution of greenPadawan:

> use "convertDocumentToString(doc.getFirstChild())" instead of
>   "convertDocumentToString(doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild())".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main method, use "convertDocumentToString(doc.getFirstChild())" instead of "convertDocumentToString(doc.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild())".

Comment: #greenPadawan: if use convertDocumentToString(doc.getFirstChild()), the  result is the same with the original xml data. i just want to get SDG.

Comment: Then you can pass the node SDG in your convertDocumentToString method. Something like convertDocumentToString(doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(1)). In this statement "1" is the index of the node SDG, in the list of children nodes of <ns2:data> node.

Comment: @nguyenmy: If you found it useful, please mark as correct or useful.